# How to run the 2nd call query in php using ajax with mutiple calls

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This is my Add query array for the table (tb_empgrocery) and this works

```
case "Add":
    $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $unitprc = $_POST['unitprc'];
    $amt = $_POST['amt'];
    $coopmemid = $_SESSION['kiosk']['is_coopmemID_kiosk'];
    for($x=0; $x<count($itemno); $x++) {
        $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount) 
                     VALUES ('$coopmemid',(NOW()),'$itemno[$x]','$qty[$x]','$unitprc[$x]','$amt[$x]')";
                     mysql_query($Addquery, $con);
    }
break;
```

This is my Save query for the table (tb_empgroc_master) and this doesn't save any data into the table. This table has many columns but I only put `data_ordered` because it is set to `timestamp` and the other columns has no value yet. I'm trying to have at least one row data in a table which is the value of the date_ordered to be shown.

```
case "Save":
    if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
        $Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (date_ordered) VALUES ((NOW()))";
        mysql_query($Savequery, $con);
    }
break;
```

This is the looping array function for the Add query

```
function saveme(){
var data = new Array();
$('#cLoanOut2 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var nodes = $(this).children();
    var itemno = nodes[0].innerHTML,
    qty = nodes[2].innerHTML,
    unitprc = nodes[3].innerHTML,
    amt = nodes[4].innerHTML;
    data.push({
        name: "itemno[]",
        value: itemno
    },{
        name: "qty[]",
        value: qty
    },{
        name: "unitprc[]",
        value: unitprc
    },{
        name: "amt[]",
        value: amt
    });
    });
        return data;
}
```

And this is my ajax request calling the 2 queries

```
$('#OKBtn2').click(function(){
    $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
    var itemid = $('#main-form2 .active').attr('id'),
    qty = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(2)').text(),
    unit_price = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(3)').text(),
    amount = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(4)').text();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            var data = saveme();
            data.push({
                name: "todo",
                value: "Add"
            });
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({  
                url : url,
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : data,  --->//This calls the first query which is Add query and it push the data array and it works for the table (tb_empgrocery)
                todo: "Save", --->//Is this right to call the Save query? Because this doesn't work for the table (tb_empgroc_master)
                success:function(result){
                    bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
                    });
                    updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

How can I call the 2nd query after that first one? Thanks in advance :))

Comment: I think the problem is in my Save query in php or in the ajax request calling the Save query in javascript jquery..

Comment: Have you set this url : url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the answer.. Thanks for helping guys
In my PHP

```
case "Add":
    $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $unitprc = $_POST['unitprc'];
    $amt = $_POST['amt'];
    $coopmemid = $_SESSION['kiosk']['is_coopmemID_kiosk'];
    for($x=0; $x<count($itemno); $x++) {
        $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount) 
                     VALUES ('$coopmemid',(NOW()),'$itemno[$x]','$qty[$x]','$unitprc[$x]','$amt[$x]')";
                     mysql_query($Addquery, $con);
    }
        $Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (date_ordered) VALUES ((NOW()))";
        mysql_query($Savequery, $con);
break;
```

In javascript

```
$('#OKBtn2').click(function(){
    $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
    var itemid = $('#main-form2 .active').attr('id'),
    qty = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(2)').text(),
    unit_price = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(3)').text(),
    amount = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(4)').text();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            var data = saveme();
            data.push({
                name: "todo",
                value: "Add"
            });
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({  
                url : url,
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : data,
                success:function(result){
                    bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
                    });
                    updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Jquery there is no todo option. [see me](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You need to refactor your function. Extract ajax function and use it twice with different input arguments.

The code will be something like this. I didn't test it.

```
function SaveData(data) {
        $.ajax({  
            url : url,
            type : "POST",
            async : false,
            data : data,
            success:function(result){
                bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
                });
                updateTable();
            }
        });
}


 $('#OKBtn2').click(function(){
$('#myModal2').modal('hide');
var itemid = $('#main-form2 .active').attr('id'),
qty = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(2)').text(),
unit_price = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(3)').text(),
amount = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(4)').text();
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?","No","Yes",function(r){
    if(r) {
        var data = saveme();
        data.push({
            name: "todo",
            value: "Add"
        });
        //Use this in codition
        /*data.push({
            name: "todo",
            value: "Save"
        });*/
        console.log(data);
        SaveData(data);
    } else {

    }
});
```

});